# Subcounter (Korollar, Beispiel(=Example), Bemerkung(=Remark) it is german) does not reset, when creating new Theorem, Satz etc

Tags: counters, amsthm

I have this environments:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{bemerkungdefinition}{Bemerkung}[definition]
\newtheorem{beispieldefinition}[bemerkungdefinition]{Beispiel}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{satz}[definition]{Satz}
\newtheorem{korollarsatz}{Korollar}[satz]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{beispielsatz}[korollarsatz]{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{bemerkungsatz}[korollarsatz]{Bemerkung}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{korollartheorem}{Korollar}[theorem]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{beispieltheorem}[korollartheorem]{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{bemerkungtheorem}[korollartheorem]{Bemerkung}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{korollarproposition}{Korollar}[proposition]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{beispielproposition}[korollarproposition]{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{bemerkungproposition}[korollarproposition]{Bemerkung}


\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{korollarlemma}{Korollar}[lemma]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{beispiellemma}[korollarlemma]{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{bemerkunglemma}[korollarlemma]{Bemerkung}
```

So for example if I do this

```
%first satz
\begin{satz}
    satz1
\end{satz}
\begin{korollarsatz}
    korollar1.1
\end{korollarsatz}
%second satz
\begin{satz}
    satz2
\end{satz}
\begin{korollarsatz}
    korollar2.1
\end{korollarsatz}
```

Instead of counting the second corollary as 2.1, it goes 2.2 as a continuation of the first corollary which is a part of the first satz. I want it to reset the counter.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: There is no `satz` counter. You want `\newtheorem{korollarsatz}{Korollar}[definition]`